# Dropzone js and Verot's upload, how to upload to dynamic folder?

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, upload, dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone.js and Verot's class.upload.php to create a simple upload file.
I want to have images upload to folders dynamically from a $_GET[] variable.

Below is the code I have, but no matter what I do, all files get uploaded to "uploads" folder.

upload.php

```
<?php include('includes/php/class.upload.php');  ?>

<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone"></form>

<?php

$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$filesFolder = 'uploads';

if(isset($_GET['album'])){
$targetDir = dirname(__FILE__).$ds.$filesFolder.$ds.$_GET['album'];
}else{
$targetDir = dirname(__FILE__).$ds.$filesFolder;
}

if(!empty($_FILES)){

$handle = new upload($_FILES['file']);

if ($handle->uploaded) {
    $handle->image_resize         = true;
    $handle->image_x              = 960;
    $handle->image_ratio_y        = true;
    $handle->process($targetDir);
}
}



?>`
```

So, if the url is index.php?album=rocks, images should get uploaded to "uploads/rocks". But, right now all gets uploaded to "uploads".

If I change the $filesFolder variable directly to "uploads/rocks" file uploads to the intended folder.

Am I doing something wrong? or is there a better way to achieve this besides using $_GET.

Comment: for file uploads your form must have the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Are you trying to allow folder upload?

Comment: @guest271314 No, only image uploads to dynamic folder based on the $_GET variable

Comment: @Franco, thanks. I added to my form but still the files don't upload to the folder from the GET variable. <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is the $_GET['album'] does not exist based on your current code, So the extended path never gets created.  You must use a hidden input in your form for a GET request.  But also be advised if your plan on using this code in on a live website or software please properly secure the data with validation and sanitization.

```
<form action = "upload.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="dir" value="album"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you give me an example? Thanks

Comment: You must use a post to send it as a hidden form i miss spoke. Been while since i have done forms :)

Comment: Ah... I see what you mean. Thanks! It works now from your advice! :) Also, note taken about the validation of it. I changed it to $_POST and it's all working nicely.